# Cypress request method won't decode special characters

Tags: javascript, api, request, cypress, decoding

I am writing a few API calls which are intertwined and pass on values to each other, there's a get token and store call then an get list of users and store user_id in order for both of those to be forwarded to the third DELETE user api call. The issue im encountering is with the url forming in the delete request. There's a special character in the user_id which is '|' this one. Notably when i pass the JS function decodeURIComponent on it, i get a proper result and the | character. But when calling the decoded variable inside the Cypress request method url option. It keeps ignoring the decode and encoding the character no matter where i try to put decodeURIComponent.

Heres a few examples of the method i tried using

```
Cypress.Commands.add('deleteCreatedUser', (token, user_id) => {
  var userid = decodeURIComponent(user_id)
  cy.log(userid)
  cy.request({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: "https://companydomain.auth0.com/api/v2/users/" + `${userid}`,
    auth: {
      bearer: `${token}`
    }
  })
    .then((resp) => {
      expect(resp.status).to.eq(204)
    })
})
```

Or

```
Cypress.Commands.add('deleteCreatedUser', (token, user_id) => {
  // var new_url = "https://companydomain.auth0.com/api/v2/users/" + `${decodeURIComponent(user_id)}`
  // cy.log(new_url)
  cy.request({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: "https://companydomain.com/api/v2/users/" + `${decodeURIComponent(user_id)}`,
    auth: {
      bearer: `${token}`
    }
  })
    .then((resp) => {
      expect(resp.status).to.eq(204)
    })
})
```

Or

```
Cypress.Commands.add('deleteCreatedUser', (token, user_id) => {
  var new_url = "https://companydomain.auth0.com/api/v2/users/" + `${decodeURIComponent(user_id)}`
  cy.log(new_url)
  cy.request({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: new_url,
    auth: {
      bearer: `${token}`
    }
  })
    .then((resp) => {
      expect(resp.status).to.eq(204)
    })
})
```

All produce the same error message, the cy.log output is correctly:
[https://companydomain.auth0.com/api/v2/users/auth0|63c92d19bc49af9a23ede481](https://companydomain.auth0.com/api/v2/users/auth0%7C63c92d19bc49af9a23ede481)
but in the cypress request method that fails the URL is:
https://companydomain.auth0.com/api/v2/users/auth0%7C63c92d19bc49af9a23ede481

I am on Cypress version 12.3.0

So the decoding won't work in the Cypress request method, does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: The url encoding happens automatically. If you use native browser fetch like this: fetch("https://companydomain.auth0.com/api/v2/users/auth|C63c92d19bc49af9a23ede481") then you'll see that even there the | character is replaced by %7C, and rightfully so because only ascii characters are supposed to be in an url. So here the backend should accept the encoded url, and decode it in its side imo

Comment: In the fetch example I had the | character - but even Stack Overflow seems to encode the url automaticcaly...